# How to Use Different Xibs View Controller for PageViewController Walkthrough

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Walkthrough Page am working on, i intend using a xibs for all views rather than making a dynamic view controller for the walkthrough.

I put in my best to achieve this but when I scroll to the second xib in the page controller, it shows a blank screen.

Could anyone provide a library or already made project that can enhance my thinking or perhaps

Comment: https://github.com/iltercengiz/ICViewPager look at this.

Comment: Good! but this was not what I needed for, Fantastic nyekimov. Thank you. I'm keeping this for future use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use EAIntroView. https://github.com/ealeksandrov/EAIntroView. You could easily add it to your project using cocoa pod.

```
//Springboard view is just subclass of a UIView

SpringboardView *viewPage1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Springboard1" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
viewPage1.titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome Title 1", @"");
viewPage1.messageLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome Message 1", @"");
[viewPage1.bottomButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome Button", @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
EAIntroPage *page1 = [EAIntroPage pageWithCustomView:viewPage1];

SpringboardView *viewPage2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Springboard2" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
viewPage2.titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome Title 2", @"");
viewPage2.messageLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome Message 2", @"");
[viewPage2.bottomButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome Button", @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
EAIntroPage *page2 = [EAIntroPage pageWithCustomView:viewPage2];


EAIntroView *springboardView = [[EAIntroView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andPages:@[page1, page2]];
self.springboardView.useMotionEffects = true;
[self.springboardView setDelegate:self];
[self.springboardView showInView:self.view animateDuration:0.3];
```

Comment: I tried modifying the sample code to a from TableViewController to UIViewController. I followed the steps on Github but am still seeing a blank black screen and a Skip button at the bottom right.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you can share your code. That way it's easy found out what going wrong.

Comment: @user3082330 I got a solution to it, I guess I was scared to twist the code, but I eventually got it right when I modify the code. Thank you.